# MySQL: COLUMN_DEFAULT is always NULL for non null default values

Tags: mysql, null, default, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`c1` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`c2` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

In the information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT contains NULL for both c1,c2 columns but c2 doesn't have default value.

How to get the real COLUMN_DEFAULT value?

Comment: `COLUMN_DEFAULT contains NULL for both c1,c2 columns` is not correct, you `c2` column is set `NOT NULL`, then how it is come null ? and what did you mean by `COLUMN_DEFAULT` value ?

Comment: Check schemata and you will see that information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT is set to NULL (if you do not mention default value). Select queries to schemata return NULL value for COLUMN_DEFAULT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `information_schema.columns`, if `COLUMN_DEFAULT` is `NULL` and `IS_NULLABLE` is `NO` then it doesn't have a default.

But basically you can see it as: the default, if not specified, is always `NULL`. So, `c2` isn't allowed to be `NULL`, but it will default to `NULL`, thus will always need to be specified on insert statements.

Note: a field specified as `NOT NULL` doesn't need to be able to represent `NULL`, thus it can theoretically take up (slightly) less space.

Comment: So how to get the real default value from schemata?

Comment: If you try to INSERT INTO `test` (id,c1) VALUES (1,NULL) then the error will be occurred that c2 doesn't have default value. So how can I know if c2 default value is set to null or c2 doesn't have default value?

Comment: So how can I know if c2 default value is set to null and I can ignore c2 column in INSERT statement or c2 doesn't have default value and I must include c2 column value?

Comment: If `COLUMN_DEFAULT` is `NULL` and `IS_NULLABLE` is `NO` then you need to specify it.

Comment: And if IS_NULLABLE is YES for a column but default value is not specified then I can ignore this column in INSERT statement?

Comment: The only scenario where there isn't a default is the one mentioned above. Otherwise the default is the value of `COLUMN_DEFAULT`, even if it's NULL, and then it doesn't need to be in the insert statement.

Comment: i have a column with COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL and IS_NULLABLE: YES. 'show create table xxx' shows `my_column varchar(100),` and insert returns an error if this column is missing.